# Why does the scrollbar not work in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have created a scrollbar and it works perfectly fine in google chrome and firefox but not in IE. I have a feeling it has to do with the line-height property.

My Code:

Html:

```
<div id="scrollbar"><br /></div>
```

Css:

```
#scrollbar {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 220px;
    float: right;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    line-height: 403px;
}
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Anthony1/s9sycey1/).

Anyway to get this to work in IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `<br/>` to a `&nbsp;`. IE picks up the non-breaking space a bit better than just a `<br>` tag.
http://jsfiddle.net/s9sycey1/3/

Comment: just FYI,  OP has `</br>` instead of `<br />`

Comment: it didn't matter, even with the improper `</br>` fixed to `<br />` IE for me didn't like it

Comment: Thank you! This is better than my answer.

Comment: @scrappedcola I'm aware of that, it was just to let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of `<br />` I used `<span class="hidden">/</span>` and I set my css to `.hidden { visibility: hidden }`. Here is my updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Anthony1/s9sycey1/2/).